# How to mock React Native component in testing?

Tags: unit-testing, react-native

During testing React Native projects I got errors on `require`ing native components. How would you solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look on https://github.com/lelandrichardson/react-native-mock
It is intended exactly for mocking RN native components.